# How to code relative paths in PHP/HTML efficiently and quickly?

Tags: php, html, directory, relative-path

I've managed to teach myself PHP/PDO/SQL, and yet, I cannot for the life of me figure out how relative paths work in PHP & HTML. I've got a multipage website with a few directories and branches, and I want to be able to create a simple template I can use to make new pages, without having to change the links to my stylesheets and PHP includes every time, depending on directory.

Here's my layout as follows:

```
 MySite (http://localhost/MySite/)
   RESOURCES //Not a folder, just here for readability
   > serverside > initialize.php
   > templates  > header.php
                  footer.php
                  navuser.php
                  navmenu.php
   > styles     > styles.css
   > images     > variousImages.png

   PAGES //Not a folder, just here for readability

   > index.php
     login.php
     register.php
     gettingstarted.php

  > you         > settings    > settings.php
                > youraccount.php
                > yourfavourites.php
```

Here are the rules of the game: Each page first includes the **serverside/initialize.php** file (PHP include). Then, each page includes **styles/styles.css** through a standard HTML href attribute. Each page then includes via PHP both **templates/header.php** and **templates/footer.php**, with the former ALSO containing **templates/navuser.php**, and **templates/navmenu.php**.

The problem is, if one of the pages is in on a different level (say you/settings/settings.php, for example), then all those includes and hrefs have to change, which seemingly affects the includes inside the includes. It's impossible!

All I want is to be able to specify file names without using true absolute paths so I can have a single template file to duplicate throughout my website if needed - I've looked into `__DIR__`, `__FILE__`, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, casting a variable $dir to act as a document root, but to no success. I don't understand half of what's happening either.

Can anyone shed some light on my situation? I'm essentially looking for a complete explanation of how relative roots/links/files are meant to work in PHP. How do I deal with even more complex directory structures? Again, what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: If you doubt, write absolute paths. Then, keep 'relativizing' them.

Comment: The problem with absolute paths though is just that - they're absolute. If I one day decide to go live and switch from http://localhost/site/ to mywebsite.com, I have to change everything again. Also, some links cannot be relativized because they're used by multiple files on multiple levels, and others are dependent on each other...

Answer (score 2):

You would usually set a constant containing an absolute path and absolute URL in your **index.php** file, and then reference them from there on in includes etc.

An example **index.php**:

```
<?php
define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);
```

You can then use that constant thereafter:

```
require ROOT_DIR . '/includes/database.php';
require ROOT_DIR . '/application/controllers/MyController.php';
require ROOT_DIR . '/application/models/MyModel.php';
```

And so on. Hope this helps.

Comment: If the constant is in the index.php file, how exactly does another file on the same directory level know about the constant?

Comment: Because you would normally use **index.php** as a front controller, and everything would be included from there.